# sum of two normal distributed random variables

Tags: calculus, statistics

Consider $Z = \frac{1}{2}(X+Y)$ where X and Y are normal distributed variables.
It is easy to show that the variance of $Z$ is $1/2$ and the mean is zero.

I'm stuck because I want to show this using the convolution and I'm not sure where is my mystake, here's my integral:

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(2z-y)^2/2}e^{-y^2/2}dy
$$

I'm sure I'm missing something but I cannot find what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Just rearrange things algebraically:

$$\begin{align}\frac1{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy \, e^{-(2 z-y)^2/2} \, e^{-y^2/2} &= \frac1{2 \pi} e^{-2 z^2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy \, e^{-y^2} \, e^{2 z y}\\ &= \frac1{2 \pi} e^{-z^2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy \, e^{-(y^2-2 y z+z^2 )}\\ &= \frac1{2 \pi} e^{-z^2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy \, e^{-(y-z)^2} \\ &= \frac1{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sqrt{2}} e^{-4 z^2/(2 \cdot 2)}\end{align}$$

Thus, the variance of the random variable $2 Z$ is $2$, and the mean is zero.

Comment: @user2820579: how do you figure?  As a general rule, when a random variable $Z$ is the sum of two normally distributed random variables $X$ and $Y$, the variance of $Z$ is the sum of the variances of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @user2820579: That's why I wrote the final expression as I did.  The random variable in this case is $2 Z$, which has variance of $2 = 1+1$.  The variance of $Z$ is thus $1/4$ of $2$, or $1/2$.

Comment: Ok, I think you're right, I just wanted to see through this method $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-z^2}$ but I think it's indirect. How would you proceed if instead you have $Z=a*X+b*Z$, $a$ and $b$ real numbers?